# Ignoring folders and files on Codeship

Tags: deployment, codeship

I'm trying to figure out the best way to ignore some folders and files from my Codeship deployment process. At the moment it compiles all my assets as part of the deployment process but I don't really want it uploading node_modules to the server.

Is there a way to ignore the folder or remove the folder before deployment?

I tried deleting it after I ran grunt but I think it gets cached as it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I used was to `rm -r YOUR_PATH/node_modules` in the test pipeline after Grunt has been run.

This however seemed to have some issues when running on FTP deploy. For any of the SSH deploys it seems to work fine.